# Python read website data line by line when available

Tags: python

I  am using `urllib2` to read the data from the url, below is the code snippet :

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(urllink)
for lines in data.readlines():
  print lines
```

Url that I am opening is actually a cgi script which does some processing and prints the data in parallel. CGI script takes around 30 minutes to complete. So with the above code, I could see the output only after 3o minutes when the execution of CGI script is completed.

How can I read the data from the url as soon as it is available and print it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just loop *directly* over the file object:

```
for line in data:
    print line
```

This reads the incoming data stream line by line (internally, the socket fileobject calls `.readline()` every time you iterate). This does assume that your server is sending data as soon as possible.

Calling `.readlines()` (plural) guarantees that you read the whole request *before* you start looping, don't do that.

Alternatively, use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/), which has more explicit support for request streaming:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line: print line
```

Note that this only will work if your server starts streaming data immediately. If your CGI doesn't produce data until the process is complete, there is no point in trying to stream the data.